# Laravel: decode JSON within Eloquent

Tags: json, laravel

I need to JSON decode a certain column in my Eloquent query. Is there a way to do this without breaking all apart?

So far I have this.

```
public function index()
{
    return Offer::all();
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the model:

```
public function getColumnNameAttribute($value) {
  return json_decode($value);
}
```

or use [attribute casting](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) to tell Laravel to do it automatically:

```
protected $casts = [
    'column_name' => 'array',
];
```

> The `array` cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON.

Note that you may have to stop `json_encode`ing your data if you use casts, as Laravel will now do that step automatically as well.

Comment: Is attribute casting possible with DB class?

Comment: @Zigson No, but you should avoid direct DB calls if at all possible. You lose the benefits of things like soft deletes, relationships, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will see what can I do.

Comment: You should not have to necessarily avoid direct DB calls. Eloquent makes query a lot slower then when you are using the DB query builder. When you need performance, you should ditch Eloquent and write the queries yourself.