# how to search a array of objects with array property in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

i want query a table with a json column
the object stored in json column is like this:

```
[    
    {
        "title":"first",
        "ids":[79,583,584]
    },
    {
        "title":"second",
        "ids":[600,601,602]
    },
    {
        "title":"third",
        "ids":[605,606,624]
    }
]
```

and for example i want to find a row where one of its `ids` property contain  for  example 79. something like this:

```
Model::query()->whereJsonContains('data', ['ids[*]' => 79])->first();
```

i,ve searched a lot and tried some syntaxes but nothing worked. is that possible to do? how?
my database is mysql

Comment: you can do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804878/laravel-decode-json-within-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

querying nested json formats might not be available as of now, you can try filtering the eloquent collection though.

you have to cast the json data column as array on your model first and then filter the collection as per your conditions.

```
$id = 8;
$filtered = Model::all()->filter(function($item, $key) use($id) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($item->data as $data) {
        if(in_array($id, $data['ids'])) {
            $count += 1;
        }
    }
    return $count > 0;
})->all();
```